# HTTP POST to iFrame

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, iframe

I'm trying to integrate my website with a third party white label website, which can hosted within an iFrame from my website.

In order for the iFrame to load the website correctly, I need to issue a HTTP POST with credentials to a source url, passing the credentials as a querystring. The server will then respond, after which I then need to set the iFrame src attribute to the same URL I posted to, and then reload the page.

So, to recap, my HTTP POST should be to the following URL, dynamically setting in the id parameter from my codebehind before posting:

https://cads.mobile.com/WhiteLabelSite/Default.aspx?id=1234-1234-1234-1214

After the response, my site needs to redirect the iframe to that exact same URL. So I need to set the iFrame src to the dynamic URL before redirecting..

I'm not sure how to do this...sigh

Answer (score 0):

1. create a new page called `sitePostRedirect.aspx`
2. the purpose of that will be to make the HTTP POST action and then redirect to the required URL.
3. You can make the post using a form and a submit button click emulation or any other method.
4. Direct your IFrame to use `sitePostRedirect.aspx` wich will handle everything from that point.

**sitePostRedirect.aspx:**

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="http://someurl.com" runat-"server"/>
   <asp:hiddenfield id="ValueHiddenField" value="" runat="server"/>
</form>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#myForm').submit();
  });
</scrip>
```